# Value of sine 180 is coming out as 1.22465e-16

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, ios4, trigonometry

I want to implement a Sine and Cosine calculator in ios4:

```
if([operation isEqual:@"sin"]){
    operand = (operand*M_PI/180.0);
    operand=sin(operand);
}
```

The code gives me correct answer for values from 0 through 90.

When I give value of 180, I get `1.22465e-16` as an answer.  I expect zero.

Where does this small difference come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the inability of a binary number system to exactly represent PI.

One possible solution would be to use the symmetry of sin:

```
sindeg(x) = sindeg(180 - x)
```

(or alternatively):

```
sin(x) = sin(M_PI - x)
```

Transforming the angle into the range (-pi/2 : pi/2) reduces the error of the approximation.

Basically:

```
if([operation isEqual:@"sin"]){
  operand = fmod(operand, 360);
  if (operand > 270) operand -= 360;
  else if (operand > 90) operand = 180 - operand;
  operand=sin(operand*M_PI/180.0);
}
```

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but I'm guessing that it's because of your second expression, which will actually be *less* accurate than a typical math library implementation (exactly because pi isn't representable).

Comment: @Stephen: It's less accurate for small x, but much more accurate for x near pi (if `x` is being calculated in terms of `M_PI`, which the question does).

Comment: Code looks troublesome for `operand < 0`. If `fmod(small_negative, 360);` returns a value just under 360.0, that is serve loss of precision.  If `fmod(any_negative, 360);` returns a negative, `if (operand > 270) operand -= 360;   else if (operand > 90) ...` does not help.  Otherwise the range reduction in degrees is a good first step.

Answer (score 8):

Just to be clear, your program *is* giving you the **correct answer**.  That is to say, it is doing exactly what you told it to do in your code.

`180*M_PI` is correctly rounded (per IEEE-754), and gives the value:

```
565.4866776461627750904881395399570465087890625
```

dividing that by 180 is also correctly rounded, and gives the result:

```
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

which is not *exactly* the mathematical value of π.  In fact, it is:

```
π - 0.0000000000000001224646799147...
```

the first order term of the Taylor series for `sin(x)` around π is (π-x), so `sin(π - x)` is, for small `x`, nearly exactly `-x`.  In fact, the result that you're getting is the *correctly rounded result*.  The library couldn't possibly deliver a more accurate answer.

As **Ben Voigt** suggested, if this is actually a problem for you, you can work around it by reducing the argument into the range [-90, 90) before converting from degrees to radians.  An even better suggestion is **njuffa**'s to use a `sinpi` function that will do this work for you.  iOS does not have such a function, but it does have `vvsinpi`, which implements sin(π*x) for vectors, and can be made to do what you want:

```
double result;
int vectorLength = 1;
vvsinpi(&result, &operand, &vectorLength);
```

Please also file a bug requesting that `sinpi` be added to the math library as an extension.

Comment: `__sinpi()` is available as of iOS 7 and OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check whether the math library on this platform offers the function sinpi() as an extension to the C/C++ standard math library functions. This would avoid explicit multiplication with the approximate value of pi (i.e. M_PI) and give you improved accuracy.

```
operand = sinpi (operand / 180.0)
```

Comment: if you need, also available with __cospi(val/180), __tanpi(val/180)

Answer (score -1):

You rely on the floating point datatype in your processor. With (quite considerable) more effort you can implement an arbitrary precision datatype. Look at MPFR http://www.mpfr.org/sample.html it contains definition for functions (like sin) that will deliver a higher number of digits.